# How to run multiple scripts in a python script with args

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm still new to python and I have multiple scripts that I have to pass arguments into to run. They were all setup to run in the command line like:

```
python script1 -c config/config_file1.json -m import

python script2 -c config/config_file1.json -cl config/config_file2.json 

python script3 -c config/config_file3.json -d name
```

I now I have to create a script to run all the the scripts above and I don't know even where to begin. I've seen sugestions for **subprocess** or **sys.argv**, but I don't know what's the best aproach for this case. All I need is to be able to run the main script to run all the 3 other scripts and know the best way to handle all the args I need to pass to them. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the content of the different scripts as well? This question can be answered without having the content, but it would probably improve your script if we would know the content of the scripts so that we know which functions to call.

Comment: Basically the scripts are for different steps of a pipeline, one donwloads the files from cos, the other does some changes into the data and ingests into a local mongodb, and the third ingests the data into de mongodb in the cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arguments for the scripts are static, then:

```
import subprocess


# This is like running `python script1 -c config/config_file1.json -m import` and your other commands
subprocess.call(["python", "script1", "-c", "config/config_file1.json", "-m", "import"])
subprocess.call(["python", "script2", "-c", "config/config_file1.json", "-cl", "config/config_file2.json"])
subprocess.call(["python", "script3", "-c", "config/config_file3.json", "-d", "name"])
```

If you need to pass in different arguments every time, then you can get them from `input()` or the `argparse` library (Personally prefer `argparse` in this case):

```
import argparse
import subprocess


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # The add_argument method takes this pattern: ("--flag", "-abreviated-flag", dest="variable_to_store_input", help="Help message to display for partcular argument")
    parser.add_argument("--name", "-n", dest="name", help="Name to enter: --name Bill, OR -n Bill")
    parser.add_argument("--age", "-a", dest="age", help="Age to enter: --age 21, OR -a 21")
    # Add as many arguments as you need following this format.

    args = parser.parse_args()  # Collect and parse the inputed arguments

    # Make sure needed arguments are there
    if not args.age:
        parser.error("No age specified! Use --help for more info.")

    if not args.name:
        parser.error("No name specified! Use --help for more info")

    return args  # If this line is reached, all of the arguments are filled


arguments = get_args() # Gets the arguments
name = arguments.name
age = arguments.age

# This is just like running the command: `python script1 --name <some-name> --age <some-age>`

subprocess.call(["python", "script1", "--name", name, "--age", age])
# You can also store the command:
command = ["python", "script1", "--name", name, "--age", age]
subprocess.call(command)
```

Comment: Obviously change the variables and command structure for your use case. `name` and `age` are just examples.